# Can We use one UIViewController class for tab-bar's

Tags: iphone

Can We use one UIViewController class for tab-bar application. Which has two tabs''  need to bind data in UIViewController with out effecting data in UIViewController when tab is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Just add a UITabBarController (which you are going to need anyway) and subclass it if necessary. You'll probably want to have an extra view controller for each view displayed in a tab anyway.

Comment: Marschollek.. Thanks ... My ViewController is Similar sir..... I need to maintain data different.. for both tab's first tab its displays List of name ... for second tab it displays list of cities..... do i can manage with this single UIViewController class.....

Comment: This is probably not the way Apple suggests it in its Human Interface Guidelines, but you can do this using a UITabBarController, which is a subclass of UIViewController.